# In bash, why does the "local" keyword pass function arguments?

Tags: bash

In bash, it seems you can use the "local" keyword to refer to input arguments to a function. Is this documented behaviour? If so, where can I read about it?

```
$ f() { local g; for g; do echo $g; done; }
$ f foo bar
foo
bar
```

According to https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html

> local [option] name[=value] …
>   For each argument, a local variable named name is created, and assigned value.

But I see nothing about assigning the function's $1, $2 etc to the variable if no other value is provided.

I am more familiar with doing it this way:

```
for g in "$@"
```

Is either way better? More cross-compatible?

My bash on macOs 10.14:

> GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
>   Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: `help local` might help.

Comment: @Cyrus, Thanks. This is what it says "Create a local variable called NAME, and give it VALUE.  LOCAL
    can only be used within a function; it makes the variable NAME
    have a visible scope restricted to that function and its children." So, what about input arguments?

Comment: It has nothing to do with function arguments. It's talking about the arguments to the `local` command itself.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, but why does "local g" cause "g" to get the function arguments?

Comment: Because that's what `for g` does.

Comment: Try it without `local g` and it works the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `local` command. When you use the `for` command without the `in` clause, it defaults to looping over the positional arguments.

```
for g
```

is equivalent to

```
for g in "$@"
```

This is in the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#Looping-Constructs)

> If *‘in words’* is not present, the `for` command executes the *commands* once for each positional parameter that is set, as if `in "$@"` had been specified (see [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters)).

Comment: aha! so what's the purpose of the "local g"?

Comment: It makes the variable local to the function, rather than being a global variable visible in the rest of the script.